# How to add Chat from jzy3d 3rd library to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

There is the following code:

```
public class SurfaceViewerFrame extends JFrame {

    public SurfaceViewerFrame() {
        setResizable(false);
        //System.loadLibrary("lib/jogl2-rc10/gluegen-rt.jar");
        Settings.getInstance().setHardwareAccelerated(true);
        FormLayout layout=new FormLayout("10px, 300px, 10px", "30px, 10px, 20px, 300px, 10px");
        CellConstraints сс=new CellConstraints();

        JLabel title=new JLabel("Выходная поверхность");


        Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
            public double f(double x, double y) {
                return x * Math.sin(x * y);
            }
        };
        // Define range and precision for the function to plot
        Range range = new Range(-300, 300);
        int steps = 80;

        // Create the object to represent the function over the given range.
        final Shape surface = Builder.buildOrthonormal(new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
        surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface.getBounds().getZmin(), surface.getBounds().getZmax(), new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
        surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
        surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);

        // Create a chart
        Chart chart = new Chart(Quality.Advanced, "awt");
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
        chart.addController(new CameraKeyController());

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.add(title, сс.xy(1, 1));
        panel.add((JComponent)chart.getCanvas(), CC.xy(1, 3));
        add(panel);
        setSize(320, 370);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've made Chart object, then I need to add it to the special place in my JFrame. But when I try to use this construction I've got the exeption about casting chart.getCanvas() to JComponent. Please, tell me, how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Canvas` isn't a `JComponent` - it's an awt `Component`.  You shouldn't need to make the cast in the first place, but if you do, cast it to `Component` instead.

```
panel.add((Component)chart.getCanvas(), CC.xy(1, 3));
```

See [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) for more information